# Firebird Stored Procedure syntax - rejecting ;

Tags: stored-procedures, syntax, firebird

I am trying to create the following stored procedure in Firebird but I must be getting the syntax wrong as it is complaining as follows:

```
Statement #3:
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 23, column 46
;
```

The stored procedure itself is as follows - what am I doing wrong?

```
SET AUTODDL OFF;
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_KPI
(
  STAFFID INTEGER,
  FROM_DATE DATE,
  TO_DATE DATE
)
RETURNS
(
  FORENAME VARCHAR(50),
  SURNAME VARCHAR(50),
  STATUSNAME VARCHAR(50),
  STATUS_COUNT INTEGER
)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT s.forename, s.surname, v2.statusname, count(v2.statusname) as STATUS_COUNT
     FROM Vacconthist v
     JOIN Staff s ON v.staffid=s.staffid
     JOIN Vacstatus v2 ON v2.statusid=v.status
    WHERE (s.staffid = 867) AND (v.LASTUPDATE BETWEEN '01-Jan-2011' AND '08-Mar-2011') AND (v.status > 9 AND v.status < 99999)
GROUP BY s.forename, s.surname, v2.statusname;
END
^

SET TERM ; ^
COMMIT WORK;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You missed INTO clause! the select should look like:

```
   SELECT s.forename, s.surname, v2.statusname, count(v2.statusname) as STATUS_COUNT
     FROM Vacconthist v
     JOIN Staff s ON v.staffid=s.staffid
     JOIN Vacstatus v2 ON v2.statusid=v.status
    WHERE (s.staffid = 867) AND (v.LASTUPDATE BETWEEN '01-Jan-2011' AND '08-Mar-2011') AND (v.status > 9 AND v.status < 99999)
GROUP BY s.forename, s.surname, v2.statusname INTO :FORENAME, :SURNAME, :STATUSNAME, :STATUS_COUNT;
```